# How to prevent spring boot app from starting

Tags: spring-boot

How to prevent the app from starting if it cannot inject a `Resource` ?

I've noticed that whether the path exists or not the app starts anyway:

```
@Value("classpath:insurance/template/insurance_policy.docx")
private Resource insuranceTemplate;
```

How to prevent the app from starting if the path doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent your application from starting if the resource cannot be injected by throwing an exception during initialization. One way to achieve this is by using the `@PostConstruct` annotation on a method in your application's configuration or startup class, like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Resource insuranceTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void validateResource() {
        if (!insuranceTemplate.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Insurance template not found");
        }
    }
}
```

the `validateResource()` method is annotated with `@PostConstruct`, which means it will be called after all the dependencies have been injected. The method checks if the `insuranceTemplate` resource exists, and if not, it throws an exception. This will prevent the application from starting.

This will work if you are using Spring Framework and the Resource interface from the `org.springframework.core.io` package.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor injection is a better approach. It simplifies writing unit tests and enforces to pass of all necessary dependencies and once we create a bean, we cannot alter its dependencies anymore.

Below you can find example code:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;


@Configuration
public class InsuranceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    InsuranceFacade insuranceService(@Value("${:classpath:test.txt}")Resource resource){
        return new InsuranceFacade(resource);
    }

}
```

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;


import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;

public class InsuranceFacade {

    private final Resource resource;

    public InsuranceFacade(final Resource resource) {
        checkArgument(resource.exists(), "resource cannot be null");
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I solved it in the following way:

```
private Resource insuranceTemplate;

public InsuranceService(
...
@Value("classpath:insurance/template/insurance_policy2.docx") Resource insuranceTemplate
) {
...
        this.insuranceTemplate=insuranceTemplate;
        if (!insuranceTemplate.exists()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Insurance template not found");
        }
}
```

The exception is thrown from the service constructor